# How do I search for a keyword in a file and print out the string following the keyword?

Tags: perl, bash, sed, vi

I want to search for keyword "mykey = " in a file and print out the string that is following the keyword.
I cannot do a "grep", because each line is very long. I just want to extract the string following the keyword.

Comment: How is this string delimited? From the `=` to the end of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. Not first, but works, and without the final grep.

```
grep 'mykey = ' file | sed 's/.*\(mykey = [A-Za-z]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Don't even need the grep: sed '/mykey = /s/...'

Comment: @glennjackman I'm not following you. What is the `...`? If I simply remove the `grep` from my solution, I'll get every nonmatching line unchanged, and the matching line will be appropriately shortened. If you write out your solution explicitly, I'm sure I'll learn something, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: In sed, the "s" command does not have to operate on every line: you can specify which lines to use "s" on. For example `seq 1 9 | sed '/[2468]/s/./&&/'` -- the "s" command only kicks in for even numbers. In this case, I was not entirely correct -- to remove the "grep" from your pipeline: `sed -n '/mykey = / {s/.*\(mykey = [A-Za-z]*\).*/\1/; p}'` -- this will ignore any line not matching "/mykey = /"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keyword is a single word and a space follows it, like this:
mykey = myCoolValue

`grep 'mykey' /your/file/here | sed -r 's/.*mykey = (^[ ]*) .*/\1/g'  | grep .`

Comment: what does "sed -r" do? My sed only supports sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
.

Comment: also, if i do a sed -s 's/.*mykey = (^[ ]*) .*/\1/g'. It says "sed: 1: "s/.*errorCode=(^[ ]*) . ...": \1 not defined in the RE"

Comment: Ah, thought you were on linux. Use -E instead of -r, it just enables extended regular expressions, although you might not need it on mac, not sure, try it with/out. You shouldn't need sed -s

Comment: Also, the `| grep .` isn't needed, was a carryover from first time I tested it before adding the grep before.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pcregrep at hand, you can issue this command in terminal or in a script to get only desired text after `mykey =`

```
$ pcregrep -o '(?<=mykey = ).+' file
```

The regex uses a positive lookbehind, where `-o` returns only the matched text, not the whole line.